# Ошибка Conda HTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, conda

При исполнении команды:

```
conda create --name MyEnv django
```

Выходит

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.

HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/curr
ent_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Вариант с --set ssl... пробовал, изменений нет.
Доступ к анаконде открыт.

Answer (score 1):

необходимо запустить команду

> conda init